# Initializing a member class of an object using a non-default constructor in C++

Tags: c++, class, class-members, boost-random

I have a specific situation where I've got an object that I want to use the boost random number generators on, and it has lead to a greater question which I cannot seem to answer.  Here is the example code of what I'm trying to produce.

First, my header:

```
Class MyObject {

 protected:
    double some variable;
    boost::random::mt19937 rgenerator;
    boost::uniform_real<double> dist_0_1;
    boost::variate_generator< boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_real<double> > rand01
}
```

Now what I want to do is:

```
Class MyObject {

 protected:
    double some variable;

    boost::random::mt19937 rgenerator(std::time(0)); //initialize to a "random" seed
    boost::uniform_real<double> dist_0_1(0,1); //set the distribution to 0-1
    boost::variate_generator< boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_real<double> > rand01(rgenerator, dist_0_1);//tell it to use the above two objects
}
```

But this doesn't work because it is in a header.  I thought I could use the constructor of MyObject to somehow call the constructors on the various sub-objects (distribution, generator, but I can't figure out how.  By the time the constructor of MyObject is called, the sub-objects' default constructors have already been called, and I haven't found that they have member methods to reset these properties... besides which, that isn't the point where I am confused.  Now maybe there are too many things going on and I'm confusing issues, but as far as I can tell, my problem reduces to this following, childish example:

```
Class Tree {

    Tree();
    Tree(int);

    protected: 

        fruit apples(int);
}

Tree::Tree() {
    apples(0); //won't work because we can't call the constructor again?
}

Tree::Tree(int fruit_num) {
    apples(fruit_num); //won't work because we can't call the constructor again?
}

Class Fruit {

    public:
        Fruit();
        Fruit(int);

    protected:
        int number_of_fruit;

}

Fruit::Fruit() {

    number_of_fruit = 0;
}

Fruit::Fruit(int number) {

    number_of_fruit = number;

}
```

I'm sure this is second nature to everyone else out there, but I can't find an article that talks about the best practice for initializing member objects of an object to a non-default constructor value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is an initializer list. For example:

```
Tree::Tree(int fruit_num) 
    : apples(fruit_num) // Initializes "apple" with "fruit_num"
{
}
```

You simply add a colon (`:`) after the constructor parameters and before the opening brace `{`. You can separate different member constructors with commas (`,`). Example:

```
Tree::Tree(int fruit1, int fruit2) : apples(fruit1), bananas(fruit2) {
}
```

Comment: +1 for explaining the other possibilities. For completeness, you can also specify the name of a base class (to use a non-default base class constructor), or (in C++11) the name of the current class (to use constructor delegation).

Comment: Thanks to everyone who suggested Initializer lists.  That was the issue.  I had seen them used, but only trivially... so I had never picked up on their actual use! They solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is relatively straightforwards. You use initializer lists.

Here's an example:

```
class MyClass {
private:
     SomeOtherType sot;
public:
    MyClass() : sot(parametersForConstructorOfSOT) {}
};
```

You can extend this to multiple member objects, of course; it can also be used to call the constructor of a parent class to initialize private entries in a parent class if you need to do something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You're so close! Just use the initialiser list syntax:

```
Tree::Tree() : apples(0) {
    // ...
}

Tree::Tree(int fruit_num) : apples(fruit_num) {
    // ...
}
```